# Android Remote Views: Resource not found Exceptions

Tags: android, android-resources, remoteview, android-remoteview

I am trying my hand at Remote Views in android. 
So I created 2 apps.
A -> Sends a bundle containing RemoteView and a string on an AIDL call.
B -> Makes the AIDL call on Button click to fetch the data and immediately launches a activity to display the Remote View.

Here is the activity I am using to display the remote view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getBundleExtra("bundle");
    RemoteViews rv = (RemoteViews) b.getParcelable("RemoteView");
    String t = b.getString("test");
    Log.i("RemoteViewDisplay","String: " + t);
    View v = rv.apply(getApplicationContext(), null);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

I am getting the string I sent along with the Remote View but I am unable to display the remote view.

Below is the code executed when AIDL is called.

```
Log.i("TimeMessageService", "getRemoteViews called.");
    int i = getCallingUid();
    PackageManager pm = service.getPackageManager();
    String name = pm.getNameForUid(i);
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(name, R.id.imageView);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("RemoteView", rv);
    b.putString("test", "testString");
    return b;
```

But I keep getting a resource not found exception for Resource ID #0x7f060000.

Any ideas where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Image View Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: I think the RemoteViews constructor expects a layout id so it should be more like `new RemoveViews(name, R.layout.something)`.

Comment: Very simple.. Open your R file. Search for this ID #0x7f060000. Here something is missing. Probably a drawable

Comment: You can get your R.java file in your gen folder. Under your project folder

Comment: @SherifelKhatib - I tried your solution. But now I am getting 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class not allowed to be inflated.

Comment: @saa - Nothing is missing. I checked.

Comment: Great. It is fixed now. Your other problem is that you are using a custom view or a view not allowed in RemoteViews. If you post your layout, someone will tell you what is not allowed. (though line #7 is a good hint for you).

Comment: Ok.. then try project clean option. It re generates your R.java file

Comment: @SherifelKhatib - I added the ImageView layout. Can you point out the error now?

Comment: @saa - I tried cleaning the project and trying again. Still no luck.

Comment: If your project supports multiple devices. Check that Resource is available in all folders. It may help you.

Comment: @yashdosi. Are you sure this is your layout only?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib -  yes this is my layout only.

Comment: @yashdosi: According to doc, you should pass your layout here. But you are giving your imageView id. RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(name, R.id.imageView);

Comment: @saa -  I tried giving the layout also. Still I am getting error - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class not allowed to be inflated

Comment: Please post your #7 line here

Comment: @saa - it is a TextView I have posted my layout above in the question.  But then I changed my ImageView to TextView.

Comment: ok... I am not getting you. Please comment your #7 line here.

Comment: @saa - here is the line you asked.     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:text="This is dummy Text"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46512/discussion-between-yashdosi-and-saa)